# How to extract a specific sub-element in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, python-3.8, sublist

I have this list:

```
victories = [[0, 7], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 6], [4, 7]]
```

I have to return all the first sub-elements, so 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

BUT

I need to sort the list according whom has the higher second sub-element, thus 7, 7, 6, 3, 2

If a first sub-element has the same second sub-element of another first sub-element, then who is lower is ranked before.

so the final list must be:

```
[0, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have any sample code to show what you've tried?

Comment: Yes, but it's bigger than this, I'm having problems only with this final part of all.

My reasoning was to create two different lists:

the first one with all the sub-lists with the same second sub-element
the second one with all the others
Then to sorted the first by who is lower and the second by who has more victories.
At the end I return another list with both first sub-elements, I don't know how to ordered it well, probably an if statement? (they are already inside two for statements)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one out using `sorted` and sort on second element first and then first like below

```
victories = [[0, 7], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 6], [4, 7]]
[i[0] for i in sorted(victories,key=lambda x : (-x[1],x[0]))]
```

Comment: This is my solution too, though I would use `sorted(victories, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)` to remove some magic math